# Disable pointer alignment

Tags: clang, clang-format

I use the following style options for pointer alignment in clang-format:

```
DerivePointerBinding: false
PointerBindsToType: false
DerivePointerAlignment: false
PointerAlignment: Left
```

I want to distinguish between pointer (`*`) and reference (`&`)
for example

```
auto& ret;
char *ch;
```

Right now both pointer(`*`) and reference(`&`) either align to left, right or middle.

How do I disable alignment for pointer only?

Comment: `PointerBindsToType` is legacy (is not anymore documented in https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html, you have to go back to previous versions to see it, for example [3.4](https://releases.llvm.org/3.4/tools/clang/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)), just use `PointerAlignment` (either `Left`, `Right` or `Middle`).

Answer (score 3):

Not possible. You can only pick either Left or Right.